# sublime text and breakpoints on remote PHP debugging

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug, breakpoints

I have a FreeBSD server running Apache with PHP and Xdebug, and a Mac OS client running Sublime 3.2.2 for development and debugging. Code files are exchanged between server and client using SFTP.

I can execute the code stepwise by setting `"break_on_start": true` in my Xdebug.sublime-settings. Stack trace, context, breakpoints, everything is there: debugging works in principle.

However, stopping execution at a breakpoint does not work. Also, the current position in the code is not shown during debugging (the little green or yellow arrow left to the code lines). This limits debugging to stepping through the code right from the beginning and reading the current code position from the stack.

My suspicion is that the PHP code must be enriched with debug information (i.e. breakpoints) before upload but I cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: I use PHPStorm not sublime but they might be similar in principle. For PHP Storm there are "servers mappings" like shown here http://prntscr.com/uqwb8d that have to be setup properly for the IDE to be able to understand where to point to in your local codebase for the code running on the remote server. Without these mappings, I'd get the exact behavior you describe. Perhaps sublime has similar mappings that need to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

Wesley put me on the right track, problem was the mapping between local and remote files. I finally got it working with these project settings:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "."
    },
],
"settings":
{
    "xdebug":
    {
        "url": "http://<myserver>/<serverpath>/<mytestfile>.php",
        "path_mapping": {
            "<server path to php files>" : "<local path to php files>",
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem could be seen in the server's xdebug.log file, which reported breakpoints with reference to the client's file system instead of the server's:

```
[49644] <- breakpoint_set -i 11 -n 8 -f file%3A///Users/<foo>/Documents/Development/foo/xdebugtest.php -t line
```

After fixing the path_mapping breakpoint definitions like this can were reported:

```
[49638] <- breakpoint_set -i 8 -n 5 -f file%3A///usr/local/www/<foo>/xdebugtest.php -t line
```

Note that the way of synching local and remote files (here: SFTP plugin) was irrelevant to the problem.